# Is it possible to stream audio via AVB between two Macintoshes?

Tags: audio, streaming

I have two Macs that I am trying to stream AVB between. Both machines are running Mavericks and can see other AVB devices and stream with them. However when trying to stream from one Mac to another Mac it does not function. We have tried with an iMac, two Mac Mini, a Mac Book Pro, and a Mac Air.

Is it possible to stream between two Macs for just audio? Under Audio Midi Setup the network devices is empty.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You need an avb switch, like the one from motu or presonus.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on how the avb switch would help and, if possible, provide links to the motu and/or presonus ones you're referring to. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.

Comment: Also as Gigabit Ethernet has MDX by definition, one is not needed. Connecting devices directly to a Mac has been successful, connecting between two Macs still does not function.